# Unable to login after using Custom django models

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, one-time-password

I have configured OTP with my app. And after putting otp_required decorator on desired method i am redirecting to */account/login*.

This is the default login page that comes with *two_factor* auth. After providing correct username(email) and password it returns an error.

**IMPORTANT:**

How i can check i have configured custom user models properly. what are the ways to test it out or where i am going wrong with the configurations.

i have followed this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user)

Please let me know if you required any thing further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This might help**

To check you have configured custom user properly you can do the following.

1. Try to run django's create super user command to check either it is entering in desired table or not(**python manage.py createsuperuser**)
2. Try to check if you don't have any custom password hashing techniques for your custom user.

Saver approach is to create your own authentication backend. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Thanks! Let me try to follow the docs. This is good to have custom authentication.

Answer (score 0):

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customauth.MyUser' , this is the configuration needed for the custom user model.

However if you need to refer User model in your apps after configuring the custom user model, you have to user get_user_model function. All third party apps you used also needs to follow this.

However you should reference the User model with the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting in code that is executed at import time. get_user_model() only works once Django has imported all models.

About the error you are facing , can you provide the stack trace of the error ?